# Force iPhone web app to landscape mode

Tags: iphone, safari, landscape, mode

How do you force an iPhone web app (not a native app) into landscape mode?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to force it on startup, but I found a neat way to make your content scale correctly when changing from Portrait to Landscape, especially if you're using canvas.

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.6; maximum-scale=1.0; width=device-width; "/>
  ...
</head>
```

So, as soon as your user flips the phone to landscape mode, your page will appear in the correct scale.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to force the device into landscape mode.
It is possible to **detect** when the device is in landscape mode.
See here for example javascript:
http://www.engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/2008/06/19/tutorial-building-a-website-for-the-iphone/